# How to Add Redirect from Trailing Slash in AWS Amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify

I have a Next.js app hosted on AWS Amplify.

If I go to a page that exists but add a trailing slash for example `/about/`, I get 403. But the page works if I remove the trailing slash - `/about`.

For more info, see the Github issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3373

So is there a way to add a rewrite or redirect on AWS Amplify from all urls with trailing slashes to without the trailing slash so that I can access pages with or without a trailing slash?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for Next.js apps on AWS Amplify that then solves trailing slash urls not working.

Set `trailingSlash` to `true` in `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

After doing that, it looks like AWS Amplify redirects all urls without a trailing slash to the urls with a trailing slash. And the urls with a trailing slash work too.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can add a rewrite or redirect rule in AWS Amplify to handle URLs with trailing slashes. Here's how you can do it:

```
Go to your Amplify Console and select your app.

Click on the "Rewrites and Redirects" tab in the left sidebar.

Click on the "Create Rule" button.

In the "Source Address" field, enter the pattern for URLs with trailing slashes that you want to redirect or rewrite, such as "/:path*/".

In the "Target Address" field, enter the destination URL without the trailing slash, such as "/:path".

Choose whether you want to create a rewrite or redirect rule.

Click on the "Save" button to create the rule.
```

Once you have created the rule, it should automatically handle any URLs with trailing slashes and redirect or rewrite them to the corresponding URL without the trailing slash.

Comment: It didn't work. I am still getting 403 when going to the url with the trailing slash